# Cannot configure basic Nginx server with a SPA and API

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm new to Nginx, I'm trying the basic scenario: serve my angular SPA and expose the API which is running on the same server on port 8000.
Here's a snippet from /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index index.html;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
}
```

With this config I can see my angular app at http://{my-ip}
But trying to reach the API at http://{my-ip}/api/{my-resourse-name} always results in Nginx 404.

I've made sure my API is indeed running fine on the server by making a curl request. And my firewall is disabled (so that port 80 is available).
Also tried removing trailing `/` from `location /api/`

Do I need to try the following?

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000$request_uri;
}
```

Kind of reluctant to do random things without knowing.
It just seems like the requests are not passing to `localhost:8000` at all.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you maybe try the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index index.html;
    }
    location ~* ^/api/(.*)$ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/$1$is_args$args;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
}
```

And the api is up and running on `localhost:8000` and you can access it there?

Comment: And is your API listening on requests like `localhost:8000/resource1` or at `localhost:8000/api/resource1`?

Comment: thanks for your response, my API is listening like the following: localhost:8000/resource1

Comment: Okay, so the setup above should be potentially working. Does it?